# maps initialization in c++ for implementing tries

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to implement **tries** in c++. Here is the structure I have used:

```
typedef struct tries{
    int wordCount;
    int prefixCount;
    map<int,struct tries*> children;
}tries;
```

The **initialize** method:

```
void initialise(tries *vertex)
{
    vertex = (tries*)malloc(sizeof(tries*));
    vertex->wordCount = vertex->prefixCount = 0;
    for(char ch='a';ch<='z';ch++)
        vertex->children[ch]=NULL;

}
```

The initialize method has *segmentation fault* at `vertex->children[ch]=NULL;` The fault is:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000040139a in std::less<int>::operator() (this=0x604018, 
    __x=@0x21001: <error reading variable>, __y=@0x7fffffffddb8: 97)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_function.h:236
236           { return __x < __y; }
```

What is wrong?

Comment: this is c++. Avoid `malloc` at all cost. Use `new` instead.

Comment: Now I'm not exactly a `c` expert, but I think that you're passing the wrong `sizeof` to your `malloc` and you're not adding any children to your map

Comment: Hmmm...right.You can answer this so that I can mark it as correct. But why is malloc usage incorrect?

Answer (score 6):

You should not use `malloc()` if you are working with C++. Also, you should not allocate enough memory to hold a pointer (`sizeof(tries*)`) if you need to create an object the size of a `tries`.

Use the `new` operator:

```
vertex = new tries();
```

Or even better, do not use `new` at all and avoid doing manual memory management with raw pointers, `new`, and `delete.` Consider using smart pointers instead.

Also, in C++ classes have constructors, so the `initialise()` method could actually be replaced by a constructor for `tries`:

```
struct tries
{
    tries() : wordCount(0), prefixCount(0) 
    {
        // ...
    }

    int wordCount;
    int prefixCount;
    map<int, struct tries*> children;
};
```

Comment: In fact, this would be much better as a constructor.

Comment: +1 Also using a map to hold a continuous range of integer keys seems like overkill, better to use a vector or array.